# How to Pass Context across layers Web API on OWIN

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, castle-windsor, owin

I have a Rest Service based on Web API , My controller classes are resolved using Castle Windsor IOC container , For e.g  the constructor of a controller looks like below

```
  public SalesController(IBasketManager basketmgr)
  {
  }
```

Now  Inside my Implementation of IBasketmanager I use a Factory which is based on typed factory in Windsor Castle.
 ie

```
  public class BasketManager:IBasketManager
  {
         BasketManager(ITaxfactory txfactory)
         {
         }
  }
```

But My factory creates objects based on a parameter available in the Request, which might be different for each request , How do I pass this parameter to my Factory , I might need to pass this parameter to inner layers as well i.e some kind of Context information need to be accessible from different layers in my Application , I thought of using `CallContext.SetLogicalData` method, is it a good approach? , I believe it will make the application slow. Any suggestions?.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it around explicitly. Trust me, you don't want to test (or read in a year's time) code using `CallContext`